# Twig / symfony - sharing forms sections

Tags: php, symfony, twig, templating

I have a form and some fields on this form I want to re-use on another form. There is also some javascript code that applies to these fields that should be appended to global *javascripts* block.

For now I just used *include* to output shared fields within my form. Shared fields are in separate twig file.

That works fine, but I can't figure out how to append js code from included file to javascripts block. I suspect that by using *include* I am not doing this the right way.

What is the best approach to have set of fields that can be re-used between forms?